# Filter the 1st payment of each protocol out of 500k rows of payment record

Tags: pivot-table, powerquery

I have export a report with 500k rows of transactions of each item. I need each protocol's 1st/oldest payment date. I used pivot table to get 506 protocols with each transaction number and date. But I just want each protocols first/oldest traction

I tried power query to cleaned up and then pivot it. But still cannot filer the 1st payment per protocol. As each transaction contains multiple activities with different date

Comment: Update your question with a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) of your table with a few rows (can be dummy data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **PowerPivot** add new column with this expression:

```
= 
  var thisP = [Protocol ID]
  var firstD = CALCULATE(MIN('Transaction'[Date]), ALL('Transaction'), 'Transaction'[Protocol ID] = thisP) 
  var lastD = CALCULATE(MAX('Transaction'[Date]), ALL('Transaction'), 'Transaction'[Protocol ID] = thisP)
  RETURN SWITCH([Date], firstD, "First", lastD, "Last")
```

This column with now have "First" or "Last" or "BLANK()" which you can then use for your PivotTable filter.

- Change `'Transaction'` to the name of your table.
- Change `[Protocol ID]` to the column of your "protocol ID".
- Change `[Date]` to the column of your transaction date.

---

This can also be done in PowerQuery too, if you'd like that then update your question with a sample of your table.

Comment: Protocol 

Transaction 

Transaction  Date

0902-001

1-12C16GGH

20-07-23

1-12C20NZH

22-07-23

1-12C20O26

22-07-23

1-12C3D9IF

22-07-23

1-12C3D9IK

22-07-23

1-12C3DWF5

22-07-23

1-12C3DWFA

22-07-23

1-12DN8XK2

26-08-23

1-12DN8XK9

26-08-23

1-12ERX7L6

23-09-23

1-12ERX7MK

23-09-23

1-12F2MUNV

07-10-23

1-12FAEAXM

14-10-23

1-12FDR0A5

19-10-23

1-12FDR0AA

19-10-23

1-12FDY6VV

19-10-23

1-12FDY6W0

14-10-23

1-12FJ8H82

19-10-23


114055

1-11MW68DX

21-07-22

1-122UEMJK

19-01-23

Comment: Thanks Sam, I paste the maximum allowed characters here. The format changed from Pivot table to above, not sure you can sort out easily

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77618562/edit) your question above to include the table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Do you still want the PowerQuery equivalent or all good?